# Authentication using username instead of email laravel 5.2

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

Below is my code for AuthController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
//use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use Request;
use View;
use Hash;
use DB;
use Auth;
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    protected $redirectAfterLogout = '/login';
    protected $username = 'user_name';

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
    public function showLogin()
    {
        if (Auth::check()) 
        {
            return redirect('/home');
        }
        else
        {
            return View::make('index');

        }
    }
    public function doLogin()
    {
        //echo 'test';
        $input = Request::all();

        $pass = Hash::make($input['password']);
        //print_r($input);exit;
        //echo $input['username'];exit;
        /*DB::table('admin_user')->insert(
            ['user_name' => $input['username'], 'password' => $pass]
        );*/
        if (Auth::attempt(['user_name' => $input['username'], 'password' => $input['password']])) {
            return redirect('/home');
            //return View::make('home');
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('/');
        }


    }
    public function doLogout()
    {

        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/');


    }

}
```

Below is my Route Code

```
Route::get('/',array('uses'=>'Auth\AuthController@showLogin') );
    Route::post('/login',array('uses'=>'Auth\AuthController@doLogin'));


//Route::get('/login',array('uses'=>'Login@showLogin') );

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth.basic']], function(){


    Route::get('/home',['uses'=>'Home@getHome']);
    Route::get('/logout',array('uses'=>'Auth\AuthController@doLogout') );

});
```

i am using user name instead of email id for Auth but below error is shown

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in
>   'where clause' (SQL: select * from `admin_user` where `email` = admin
>   limit 1)

below is my kernal.php code

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    ];
}
```

please help me how can i do login with username .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: error is for login or sign up ?

Comment: for login  after form submit at the route Home

Comment: I couldn't find any problem in your code :-(

Comment: can you show me your kernel file. Only routemidllewareproviders

Comment: you are talking about auth.php file?

Comment: I don;t think its the right kernel.php. The one I'm talking about must be in `app` in directory or `app/http` directory

Comment: i am only getting solution that write protected `$username = 'user_name';`
i have also write that but is not working . 
i don'y know what is going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update:

Add the `auth`  middleware to specific route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){
        Route::get('/',array('uses'=>'Auth\AuthController@showLogin') );
        Route::post('/login',array('uses'=>'Auth\AuthController@doLogin'));
        Route::get('/home',['uses'=>'Home@getHome'])->middleware('auth');//update
        Route::get('/logout',array('uses'=>'Auth\AuthController@doLogout') );
    });
```

To redirect to intended page after login replace your `doLogin()` function with following:

```
public function doLogin()
    {

        $input = Request::all();

        $pass = Hash::make($input['password']);

        if (Auth::attempt(['user_name' => $input['username'], 'password' => $input['password']])) {
            return redirect()->intended('/home');//This line is changed
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('/');
        }
    }
```

**Explaination:**
`intended()` method redirects the user to the previous page, from where the user is redirected to login page. It expects a default route as a parameter, where user will be sent if he has came here directly.

### Update 2:

add `doLogout` in your `AuthController's` constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
$this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'doLogout']);

}
```

Comment: i have use intended(); but my page keeps on login page after submit

Comment: `Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){
        Route::get('/',array('uses'=>'Auth\AuthController@showLogin') );
        Route::post('/do_login',array('uses'=>'Auth\AuthController@doLogin'));//update
        Route::get('/login',array('uses'=>'Auth\AuthController@showLogin'));
        Route::get('/logout',array('uses'=>'Auth\AuthController@doLogout') );
    });
    Route::get('/home',['uses'=>'Home@getHome'])->middleware('auth');`
i have set login form post url to do_login but after login it redirects to login url

Comment: did u chck controller sent by me ?

Comment: also, in your view do you have a code to show validation errors ?

Comment: yes i have checked it. but i think problem is because of auth middleware.
when i use auth middleware i am not able to go to home page it redirects back me to the login page

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/auth-session-killed-after-redirect-laravel-52
i think this is the problem but i am not able to found any solution for this

Comment: can you post the login form in your question ? Also, post the auth middleware.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120399/discussion-between-jaysingkar-and-doriya-maulik).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply override `$username` in AuthController by writing `protected $username = 'username'`.